# Windows Workflow 4 AppFabrix 1.1 Suspended Workflow Will Not Resume

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, appfabric

I have a WF4 workflow which is running in AppFabric 1.1 in IIS 7.5. I am trying to test the suspension and resume functionality. The workflow is configured to 'Abandon and suspend' on unhandeld exception. To force an error I put the database that the workflow application uses (not the appfabric database) into single user mode. I then put the database back into multi-user mode and attempt to resume the workflow from the IIS AppFabric UI. I get the following error:

There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe://lonmw87129/ApprovalService/PreApprovalService.xamlx/System.ServiceModel.Activities_IWorkflowInstanceManagement that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable the net.pipe binding on your IIS web site to allow workflow instance management.

see http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/appfabric-configuration-issues-net-4-net-pipe-and-role-services.aspx

> To enable the net.pipe protocol for a site, right-click the site, point to Manage Application, and then click Advanced Settings. Add “,net.pipe” to “http” in the Enabled Protocols line (with no space between “http” and the comma), and then click OK.

Comment: I am getting a slightly different error message now The message could not be dispatched because the service at the endpoint address 'net.pipe://lonmw87129/ApprovalService/PreApprovalService.xamlx/System.ServiceModel.Activities_IWorkflowInstanceManagement' is unavailable for the protocol of the address.

Comment: the above pointed me in the right direction

I made 3 change to the net.pipe protocol enabled

i) added net.pipe binding to the web site 'right mouse click the website -> edit bindings -> add -> type = net.pipe; Binding information = *'
ii) added net.pipe protocol to the web site 'right mouse click the webiste -> manage webs ite -> advance settings -> Enabled Protocols -> added ,net.pipe after http'
iii) added net.pipe protocol to the application 'right mouse click the application in inetmgr -> manage application -> advance settings -> Enabled Protocols -> added ',net.pipe' after http'